# Numbered List with 1a and 1b using Markdown?

Tags: support, markdown

I'm trying to get the numbering correct during an edit of https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5612240. The author has a list, and he/she wants items *3a* and *3b*:

```
1. ...
2. ...
3a. ...
3b. ...
```

I'm having trouble producing the numbering. I looked at [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), but I don't see how to do it.

Is it possible to have items *3a* and *3b*? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Is using letters really mandatory? Can it be nested numbers?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One way of simulating it would be to turn off the ordered list and control it manually. You do that in Markdown by placing a backslash after the number.

```
Here's how I'm trying to accomplish this:

 1\. Get the outlines of the circles (ran very fast)

     create table circle_outlines as 
     SELECT distinct ST_ExteriorRing(the_circle) AS the_geom FROM circle_list;
     create index idx_geom_circle_outlines  on circle_outlines  using gist (the_geom);
     select distinct geometrytype(the_geom) from circle_outlines ; -- LINESTRING

 2\. Combine the lines

 3A. Check out the geom type created, if interested (should be GEOMETRYCOLLECTION)

 3B. Polygonize from the merged borders (ST_Dump((ST_Polygonize(the_geom)))

 4\. Add points inside using ST_PointOnSurface(polygonized_geoms)

 5\. Calculate num_overlaps
```

> Here's how I'm trying to accomplish this:
>
> 1. Get the outlines of the circles (ran very fast)
>
> ```
>  create table circle_outlines as 
>  SELECT distinct ST_ExteriorRing(the_circle) AS the_geom FROM circle_list;
>  create index idx_geom_circle_outlines  on circle_outlines  using gist (the_geom);
>  select distinct geometrytype(the_geom) from circle_outlines ; -- LINESTRING
> ```
>
> 2. Combine the lines
>
> 3a. Check out the geom type created, if interested (should be GEOMETRYCOLLECTION)
>
> 3b. Polygonize from the merged borders (ST_Dump((ST_Polygonize(the_geom)))
>
> 4. Add points inside using ST_PointOnSurface(polygonized_geoms)
>
> 5. Calculate num_overlaps

Of course, that also means you lose the indentation, which makes it more difficult to read. You could indent each item by manually inserting spaces (`&nbsp;`), but we're getting awfully hacky now.

---

The better option is just to use a nested list.

```
Here's how I'm trying to accomplish this:

 1. Get the outlines of the circles (ran very fast)

     create table circle_outlines as 
     SELECT distinct ST_ExteriorRing(the_circle) AS the_geom FROM circle_list;
     create index idx_geom_circle_outlines  on circle_outlines  using gist (the_geom);
     select distinct geometrytype(the_geom) from circle_outlines ; -- LINESTRING

 2. Combine the lines

 3. 

  a. Check out the geom type created, if interested (should be GEOMETRYCOLLECTION)

  b. Polygonize from the merged borders (ST_Dump((ST_Polygonize(the_geom)))

 4. Add points inside using ST_PointOnSurface(polygonized_geoms)

 5. Calculate num_overlaps
```

> Here's how I'm trying to accomplish this:
>
> 1. Get the outlines of the circles (ran very fast)
>
>    ```
>    create table circle_outlines as 
>    SELECT distinct ST_ExteriorRing(the_circle) AS the_geom FROM circle_list;
>    create index idx_geom_circle_outlines  on circle_outlines  using gist (the_geom);
>    select distinct geometrytype(the_geom) from circle_outlines ; -- LINESTRING
>    ```
> 2. Combine the lines
> 3. a. Check out the geom type created, if interested (should be GEOMETRYCOLLECTION)
>
>    b. Polygonize from the merged borders (ST_Dump((ST_Polygonize(the_geom)))
> 4. Add points inside using ST_PointOnSurface(polygonized_geoms)
> 5. Calculate num_overlaps

This will even work if you have text for item #3:

> Here's how I'm trying to accomplish this:
>
> 1. Get the outlines of the circles (ran very fast)
>
>    ```
>    create table circle_outlines as 
>    SELECT distinct ST_ExteriorRing(the_circle) AS the_geom FROM circle_list;
>    create index idx_geom_circle_outlines  on circle_outlines  using gist (the_geom);
>    select distinct geometrytype(the_geom) from circle_outlines ; -- LINESTRING
>    ```
> 2. Combine the lines
> 3. <Some sample text>
>
>    a. Check out the geom type created, if interested (should be GEOMETRYCOLLECTION)
>
>    b. Polygonize from the merged borders (ST_Dump((ST_Polygonize(the_geom)))
> 4. Add points inside using ST_PointOnSurface(polygonized_geoms)
> 5. Calculate num_overlaps

Comment: That's nice. I learned two new tricks with that answer. They might be worthy of putting in the Markdown Help.

Comment: Well, I cannot edit the help file, you'll need a moderator for that. But it does seem like [nesting is covered](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists). Perhaps not explicitly enough. You have to draw the conclusion for yourself that alphabetic lists are supported. I am surprised that the `1\.` trick isn't documented there, though.

Comment: Wait is this a new thing with Markdown? Or is it just exclusive to SO/SE?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that both of these things are standard features of Markdown, and have been there since the beginning. @anubian

Comment: "TRY THIS ONE WEIRD TRICK TO GET NESTED LISTS IN MARKDOWN"

Comment: All I did was indent the nested list. Doesn't seem *that* weird. But I'm not quite sure how to interpret that last comment…

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work on GitHub... https://gist.github.com/anubiann00b/1bf7cd561e0c08ba1839

Comment: @anubian What part doesn't work? It looks like it works to me. [Notice how](https://gist.github.com/anubiann00b/1bf7cd561e0c08ba1839) if you replace all of those numbers with "1", they are not automatically fixed up into an ordered list (contrast that with the normal list at the bottom). You get the literal `1.`. That shows that the backslash *is* preventing the ordinal numbers from being interpreted as markers in an ordered list.

Comment: Oh I see; I was looking for a list with custom elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same formatting as the accepted answer to this question except that I removed the unnecessary backslashes after the list numbers, and instead enclosed the list numbers by a pair of `<span>` HTML tags to override the default markdown numbered list formatting.

The results of these modifications to the accepted answer are shown below.

1. Get the outlines of the circles (ran very fast)

```
 create table circle_outlines as 
 SELECT distinct ST_ExteriorRing(the_circle) AS the_geom FROM circle_list;
 create index idx_geom_circle_outlines  on circle_outlines  using gist (the_geom);
 select distinct geometrytype(the_geom) from circle_outlines ; -- LINESTRING
```

2. Combine the lines

3A. Check out the geom type created, if interested (should be GEOMETRYCOLLECTION)

3B. Polygonize from the merged borders (ST_Dump((ST_Polygonize(the_geom)))

4. Add points inside using ST_PointOnSurface(polygonized_geoms)

5. Calculate num_overlaps

---

This is the same example as above, except that it can be further improved by indenting numbered list items 3a and 3b with the `&nbsp;`non-breaking space HTML entity, however this breaks up the logical sequence of the list unless a new numbered list item 3 is created. As you can see, the pretty formatted numbered list shown below is easier to read than the first example.

1. Get the outlines of the circles (ran very fast).

```
 create table circle_outlines as 
 SELECT distinct ST_ExteriorRing(the_circle) AS the_geom FROM circle_list;
 create index idx_geom_circle_outlines  on circle_outlines  using gist (the_geom);
 select distinct geometrytype(the_geom) from circle_outlines ; -- LINESTRING
```

2. Combine the lines.

3. Check out the geom type created and polygonize from the merged borders.

3a. Check out the geom type created, if interested (should be GEOMETRYCOLLECTION).

3b. Polygonize from the merged borders. (ST_Dump((ST_Polygonize(the_geom)))

4. Add points inside using ST_PointOnSurface(polygonized_geoms).

5. Calculate num_overlaps.

Answer (score -6):

Easy, just use the break lines:

1. One 
   1.A One-One 
   1.B One-Two

Source code:

```
1. One <br/>
1.A One-One <br/>
1.B One-Two <br/>
```

Comment: That's not what is asked, the items shouldn't be indented.